# unix 'sort' command for inline characters

Tags: sorting, unix, command-line-interface

I have a .txt file of pumpkinsizes that I'm trying to sort by size of pumpkin:

```
name |size
==========
Joe  |5
Mary |10
Bill |2
Jill |1
Adam |20
Mar  |5
Roe  |10
Mir  |3
Foo  |9
Bar  |12
Baz  |0
```

Currently I'm having great difficulty in getting `sort` to work properly. Can anyone help me sort my list by pumpkin size without modifying the list structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table headings need special consideration, since "sorting" them will move them to some random line. So we use a two step process:
a) output the table headings. b) sort the rest numerically (-n), reverse
 order (-r), with field separator `|` (-t), starting at field 2 (-k)

```
$ awk 'NR<=2' in; awk 'NR>2' in | sort -t '|' -nr -k 2
name |size
==========
Adam |20
Bar  |12
Roe  |10
Mary |10
Foo  |9
Mar  |5
Joe  |5
Mir  |3
Bill |2
Jill |1
Baz  |0
```

Answer (score 3):

The key point is the option `-k` of `sort`. You can use `man sort` to see how it works. The solution for your problem follows:

```
sed -n '3,$p' YOUR_FILENAME| sort -hrt '|' -k 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the

```
name |size
==========
```

by using `sed` command. Then whatever is left can be sorted using `sort` command.

`sed '1,2d' txt | sort -t "|" -k 2 -n`

Here, `sed '1,2d'` will remove the first 2 lines.

Then `sort` will tokenize the data on character `'|'` using option `-t`.

Since you want to sort based on size which happens to be second token, so the token "size" can be specified by `-k 2` option of `sort`.

Finally, considering "size" as number, so this can be specified by option `-n` of `sort`.

Comment: This sorts ascending, not descending.

Comment: @Jens: Since OP did not mentioned the sort order, so kept it as default ascending order. However `-r` (reverse or descending) option can be provided in `sort` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the shell:

```
{ read; echo "$REPLY"; read; echo "$REPLY"; sort -t'|' -k2n; } < pumpkins.txt
```

That reads and prints the first 2 header lines, then sorts the rest.